# When did the demon announce they were afraid of God?

Tags: nature-of-god, demons, exorcism

Obviously, God is the all powerful.

Now of course, Demons are proud creatures, that I doubt they will be announcing they are afraid of God. They will even be waging war with God as stated in the Revelation. So my understanding is there is none in the history and even the bible that says: demons announces they fear God.

But if I am wrong, which are the instances that they stated they fear God? Are there any proofs?

Note:

This is the communication between Demons and Jesus (Mat 8:29):

Legion: “What do you want with us, Son of God? Did you come here to torture us before the proper time?”

Legion: “If you drive us out, send us into that herd of pigs.”

Even if it is implied that Jesus has more power over them, they don't even announce or say it out loud.

Comment: Sorry, we don't do verse search questions here.

Comment: exactly! It was not even in the bible. Do they? If yes, is there any proof?

Comment: I am assuming that the down vote means i am correct! Demons are not afraid of God!

Comment: James 2:19 might be the verse people are referring to.

Comment: I think that provided some insights, thanks!

Comment: Probably should be rephrased a little and posted to hermeneutics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to **curiousdannii** in the comments:

> You believe that there is one God. Good! Even the demons believe that—and shudder.

James 2:19

Comment: That seems to me to be telling believers to shudder, because demons could say they believe in one God (which they do) to trick believers into trusting them, making the believers easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

This verse has an exchange between Jesus and a group of demons, where they certainly appear to exhibit fear.[Luk 8:31 NASB] 31 They were imploring Him not to command them to go away into the abyss.

This verse indicates that demons are part of Satan's kingdom: [Luk 11:18 NASB] 18 "If Satan also is divided against himself, how will his kingdom stand? For you say that I cast out demons by Beelzebul.

This verse shows the end of Satan, and by extrapolation, his entire kingdom: [Rev 20:10 NASB] 10 And the devil who deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are also; and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever.

This verse indicates exactly why the lake of fire exists, and moreover, many take "angels" here to mean demons [Mat 25:41 NASB] 41 "Then He will also say to those on His left, 'Depart from Me, accursed ones, into the eternal fire which has been prepared for the devil and his angels;

Lastly, James 2:19 already cited sums it up nicely: [Jas 2:19 NASB] 19 You believe that God is one. You do well; the demons also believe, and shudder.

So, both Satan and the demons have reason to fear. Believers in Jesus have no reason to fear, except to "fear" God in the sense of reverence.